# R: Mix multiple columns and pick row values from one column based on a string condition

Tags: r

I have a data frame with multiple text columns. I need to output only one with row values depending on whether a string is present or not. So if my input is like:

```
Kingdom  | Phylum            | Class             | Order                |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bacteria | Firmicutes        | Negativicutes     | Selenomonadales      |
Bacteria | Bact_unclassified | Bact_unclassified | Bact_unclassified    |
Bacteria | Firmicutes        | Negativicutes     | Negativ_unclassified |
Archaea  | Euryarchaeota     | Methanobacteria   | Methanobacteriales   |
Archaea  | Euryarchaeota     | Eury_unclassified | Eury_unclassified    |
```

I want my output to be like:

```
Output               | 
-----------------------
o_Selenomonadales    |
k_Bacteria           | 
c_Negativicutes      |
o_Methanobacteriales |
p_Euryarchaeota      |
```

Being the prefixes in output rows: "k" from Kingldom, "p" from Phylum, "c" from Class and "o" from Order. Note that the key string for filtering is "_unclassified". Any ideas?

Comment: What is criteria to select a column for each row? On what basis you are expecting `Selenomonadales` in 1st row and `Bacteria` in 2nd row?

Comment: If there is '_unclassified' tag, I want to pick the previous column value, until there is no 'unclassified'.

Comment: Please have a look at answers. May be that's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using row-wise `apply` will provide an option to investigate row-wise data. Find 1st column which contains `_unclassified`. And subtract `1` to get the previous column which is desired column for that row.

Now, `substring` provides option to take 1st character for desired column to prefix with returned value.

```
df$Output <- apply(df, 1, function(x){
      idx <- length(x)   #By default value from last column will be returned 
      if(length(which(grepl("_unclassified", x))) > 0 ){
        idx <- min(which(grepl("_unclassified", x)))-1
      } 
      paste(toupper(substring(names(df)[idx], 1, 1)), trimws(x[idx]), sep = "_")
       })

# Check result of 

df["Output"]
#                 Output
# 1    O_Selenomonadales
# 2           K_Bacteria
# 3      C_Negativicutes
# 4 O_Methanobacteriales
# 5      P_Euryarchaeota
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
  "Kingdom  | Phylum            | Class             | Order                
  Bacteria | Firmicutes        | Negativicutes     | Selenomonadales      
  Bacteria | Bact_unclassified | Bact_unclassified | Bact_unclassified    
  Bacteria | Firmicutes        | Negativicutes     | Negativ_unclassified 
  Archaea  | Euryarchaeota     | Methanobacteria   | Methanobacteriales   
  Archaea  | Euryarchaeota     | Eury_unclassified | Eury_unclassified",
  sep = "|", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- read_delim(
"Kingdom  | Phylum            | Class             | Order                
Bacteria | Firmicutes        | Negativicutes     | Selenomonadales      
Bacteria | Bact_unclassified | Bact_unclassified | Bact_unclassified    
Bacteria | Firmicutes        | Negativicutes     | Negativ_unclassified 
Archaea  | Euryarchaeota     | Methanobacteria   | Methanobacteriales   
Archaea  | Euryarchaeota     | Eury_unclassified | Eury_unclassified    
", delim = "|", trim_ws = TRUE)

priority = c(Order = 1L, Class = 2L, Phylum = 3L, Kingdom = 4L)

dat %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -id) %>% 
  mutate(priority = priority[variable]) %>% 
  arrange(id, priority) %>% 
  group_by(id)  %>% 
  slice(detect_index(value, Negate(grepl), pattern = "unclassified$")) %>% 
  mutate(Output = paste(tolower(substr(variable, 1, 1)), value, sep = "_"))

# # A tibble: 5 x 5
# # Groups: id [5]
#      id variable value              priority Output              
#   <int> <chr>    <chr>                 <int> <chr>               
# 1     1 Order    Selenomonadales           1 o_Selenomonadales   
# 2     2 Kingdom  Bacteria                  4 k_Bacteria          
# 3     3 Class    Negativicutes             2 c_Negativicutes     
# 4     4 Order    Methanobacteriales        1 o_Methanobacteriales
# 5     5 Phylum   Euryarchaeota             3 p_Euryarchaeota
```

Another way using `coalesce`:

```
dat %>% 
  imap_dfc(~ paste(tolower(substr(.y, 1, 1)), .x, sep = "_")) %>% 
  mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(grepl("unclassified$", x), NA, x)) %>% 
  mutate(Output = coalesce(Order, Class, Phylum, Kingdom))

# # A tibble: 5 x 5
#   Kingdom    Phylum          Class             Order                Output              
#   <chr>      <chr>           <chr>             <chr>                <chr>               
# 1 k_Bacteria p_Firmicutes    c_Negativicutes   o_Selenomonadales    o_Selenomonadales   
# 2 k_Bacteria NA              NA                NA                   k_Bacteria          
# 3 k_Bacteria p_Firmicutes    c_Negativicutes   NA                   c_Negativicutes     
# 4 k_Archaea  p_Euryarchaeota c_Methanobacteria o_Methanobacteriales o_Methanobacteriales
# 5 k_Archaea  p_Euryarchaeota NA                NA                   p_Euryarchaeota
```